# Why this JSON is not valid?

Tags: json, validation

I have been trying but could not figure out why this JSON is invalid (when I put it on www.jsonlint.com) Can anyone help? Here is the JSON:

```
    [
    {
        "title": "COFA NEW SOUTH WALES ",
        "img": "images/uni/cofa.png",
        "desc": "One of the Best University",
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8888/ilets/app/col.html"
    },
    {
        "title": "MIDDLESEX UNIVERSITY ",
        "img": "images/1339977840.jpg",
        "desc": "Well this is Testi",
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8888/ilets/app/MIDDLESEX UNIVERSITY.html"
    },
    {
        "title": "ROYAL COLLEGE OF ARTS ",
        "img": "images/uni/1339978144.png",
        "desc": "This is One of the best University",
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8888/ilets/app/ROYAL COLLEGE OF ARTS.html"
    },
    {
        "title": "UNIVERSITY OF SCOTLAND ",
        "img": "images/uni/1339996882.gif",
        "desc": "SCOTLAND OWNS THIS UNIVERSITY",
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8888/ilets/app/UNIVERSITY OF SCOTLAND.html"
    }
]
```

Comment: It seems to validate for me on JSONlint.com

Comment: I copied and pasted your sample into JSONlint and its says 'Valid JSON'

Comment: [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com) says it's valid.

Comment: Same for me. Are you having an issue especialy in parsing this through any of the JSON APIs?

Comment: Maybe there is no problem, but some problems with UTF marker?

Comment: I don't see it's invalid [here](http://jsontoxml.utilities-online.info/)

Comment: Same here, JSONViewer in notepad++ says it's valid

Comment: Ok, this is weird. JSON is generated here: http://www.syedmujahidali.com/ilets/retrive.php Copypaste it from here on JSONlint and it says invalid. And when I copy/pasted JSON from here to stackoverflow and copy/pasted from stackoverflow to JSONlink then it says invalid.

Comment: @UmairKhanJadoon : It still say VALID JSON after copying from [here](http://www.syedmujahidali.com/ilets/retrive.php)

Comment: @UmairKhanJadoon, don't select the space before the opening `[`. It is valid JSON. Of course have you noticed that this .php script returns JSON inside HTML? So if you try to directly parse the response from this .PHP script, well, that's far from something that even closely resembles JSON.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Oh! Thanks a lot! I just noticed it is inside HTML. Silly me.

Comment: @UmairKhanJadoon : When you hit URL as "http://www.syedmujahidali.com/ilets/retrive.php", how you are displaying JSON String? Are you doing echo & json_encode()?

Answer (score 2):

The JSON you have shown in your question is valid. On the other hand the script you mentioned in your comments section (`http://www.syedmujahidali.com/ilets/retrive.php`) returns HTML, not JSON so if you attempt to parse the result of this script with a JSON parser you will obviously fail. Here's how the response looks:

```
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8"></head><body onload="abc()">
<script>
function abc(){
document.getElementById('copy').innerHTML = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
var ab=  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
}
</script>

<div id="content" style="display:none;">


[{"title":"COFA NEW SOUTH WALES "  ,"img":"images/uni/cofa.png","desc":"One of the Best University","url":"http://127.0.0.1:8888/ilets/app/col.html"},<br>{"title":"MIDDLESEX UNIVERSITY "  ,"img":"images/1339977840.jpg","desc":"Well this is Testi","url":"http://127.0.0.1:8888/ilets/app/MIDDLESEX UNIVERSITY.html"},<br>{"title":"ROYAL COLLEGE OF ARTS "  ,"img":"images/uni/1339978144.png","desc":"This is One of the best University","url":"http://127.0.0.1:8888/ilets/app/ROYAL COLLEGE OF ARTS.html"},<br>{"title":"UNIVERSITY OF SCOTLAND "  ,"img":"images/uni/1339996882.gif","desc":"SCOTLAND OWNS THIS UNIVERSITY","url":"http://127.0.0.1:8888/ilets/app/UNIVERSITY OF SCOTLAND.html"}]</div>

<div id="copy">

</div>



</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Ok, this is weird. JSON is generated here: syedmujahidali.com/ilets/retrive.php Copypaste it from here on JSONlint and it says invalid.

Looking only at the displayed text of the response from that page (see [Darin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11078069/157247) for why I make that distinction), the problem is that your response opens with a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). The BOM makes the JSON invalid. I went to that link and did a select all and copy, then pasted it into jsonlint.com, and got the "invalid token" error you're getting. So I pasted it into vim, and vim showed me the FE FF at the beginning of the text.

So the fix would be to find out why that PHP page starts with a BOM and fix that. You don't need a BOM with UTF-8.

Comment: What BOM? This PHP script returns HTML, not JSON. If the OP tries to parse directly the response from this PHP script he will fail because the script doesn't return JSON as all.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Right, if he tried to process the full response from that page directly. But I assumed he meant the text it returned, which has a BOM in it. You might want to post the HTML aspect as an answer. *Edit*: Ah, you have. :-) +1